# What "might not be a blackbird at all" in Jamaica Kincaid's "Girl"?

Tags: short-stories, jamaica-kincaid

Part of Jamaica Kincaid's "Girl" goes like this:

> don’t pick people’s flowers—you might catch something; don’t throw stones at blackbirds, because it might not be a blackbird at all; this is how to make a bread pudding;

What's being referred to here? What might "not be a blackbird at all", that would potentially be confused for a blackbird and have a stone thrown at it? Is this referring to some element of folklore, or something more reality-based (such as it's actually a crow)? Is this a cultural thing that I'm not familiar with?

Answer (score 5):

The standard interpretation of this is that the blackbird might be a shape-shifting female creature known as a "jablesse" or "diablesse" (from French "she-devil", the feminine version of the usual "diable" meaning "devil"). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Diablesse) mentions her as "a character in Caribbean folklore" but does not mention the shape-shifting aspect and how she might be seen in the form of a bird. However, various other commentators on Kincaid's work and "Girl" specifically have noted this connection.

Firstly, just to set the scene, Kincaid has [indicated in interviews](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20134506?seq=6) that "Girl" is based on the kind of advice she received as a girl growing up in Antigua. So we can assume that the setting is Antigua or somewhere culturally similar. The mother in "Girl" is influenced by both Christianity and [Obeah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obeah), a Caribbean tradition which draws upon West African roots.

Commentators on Kincaid's "Girl" have generally interpreted the "blackbird" line as follows:

> Accompanying training in preparing local food is training in folk beliefs. The reference to these suggest their mundane quality: the power of nature to do harm is taken for granted. **The blackbird might be a *jablesse*, a shape-changing female spirit whom one does not want to offend.** The fish can invoke a curse. Thus, there is a world behind the world of public appearance and performance, one which has its own authority and its own rituals.
>
> <sub>-- [Keith E. Byerman, "Anger in a Small Place: Jamaica Kincaid's Cultural Critique of Antigua", *College Literature* 22(1), *Third World Women's Inscriptions* (1995), pp. 91-102](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25112166?seq=6) (bold emphasis mine)</sub>

> Because objects may conceal spirits, the mother warns about the blackbird being something other than it appears
>
> The blackbird might be a "jablesse" (*La diablesse*, "she devil").
>
> > a shape-changing spirit that often takes the form of a beautiful, deceptive, and deadly woman.
>
> The jablesse lures men with her beauty but then isolates and devours them. (Note how the folklore reflects attitudes about female gender roles)
>
> <sub>-- [Class Notes: "Girl" by Jamaica Kincaid](https://christianealcantara.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/kincaids-girl.pptx), from the blog of [Christiane Alcantara](https://search.asu.edu/profile/3022603), an academic specialising in Caribbean literature</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The precise meaning may not be possible to pin down, because blackbird folklore varies a lot, but blackbirds have, in various manners, been regarded as connected to the Underworld.

What exactly the blackbird might be ranges from a witch to a spirit (good or evil), but at any rate, a powerful being would be offended.